# python csv find text in file and then find a specific column

Tags: python

i have a database of csv something like

```
apple,10,red,date
orange,12,yellow,date
pear,13,green,date
pineapple,14,brown,date
```

i want to first search for eg: pineapple and then get third column" from it, i need some ideas, i am using the python csv module

i am able to get

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import csv
import sys

file = open("/tmp/database.txt", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(file)
for i in reader:
   print i
```

output:

```
['apple', '10', 'red', 'date']
['orange', '12', 'yellow', 'date']
['pear', '13', 'green', 'date']
['pineapple', '14', 'brown', 'date']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just check whether the first element of the line is pineapple. A neat way to get all the third values is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import csv
with open("/tmp/database.txt", 'r') as file:
  reader = csv.reader(file)
  third_where_pineapple = [line[2] for line in reader if line[0] == 'pineapple']
  print (third_where_pineapple)
```